# R: Count number of rows in data frame, with matching character in specified position of string

Tags: r, count, character, string-matching

I have a data frame with a column with characters:

```
  strings
1 a;b;c;d
2 g;h;i;j
3     k;m
4       o
```

I would like to get a count of the number of strings(rows) with a certain specified characters at a certain position within the string.

Eg.

> Get count of number of strings with 3rd character as one of the
>   characters in this set: {a,b,m}.
>
> The output should be 2 in this case, since only the 1st and 3rd row
>   have any characters in {a,b,m} as their 3rd character within the
>   string.

I could only use this code to find any strings that contains 'b':

```
sum(grepl("b",df))
```

However, this is not good enough for the above task.
Please advice.

Comment: You're going to need to used some Regular Expressions. In this case use the "or" operator, which would be used like this: "(a|b|m)", "|" being the "or" operator. This will return any strings that have either a, b, or m in them. Replace "b" in `grepl` with "(a|b|m)".

However, I'm a little confused on the use of `grepl` because that returns a logical value of whether an item was in something or not, so I'm unsure why you are taking the sum of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(substr(df$strings,3,3) %in% c("a","b","m"))
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a `;` as the delimeter you can do:

```
sum(sapply(strsplit(df$strings,";"),function(x) x[2] %in% c("a","b","m")))
```

Comment: 1st one works. But 2nd one gave me this:
 Error in sum(lapply(strsplit(df$strings, ";"), function(x) x[2] %in%  : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: @ConanG I updated it to be `sapply()` which works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `grepl`:

```
x = c('a;b;c;d','g;h;i;j','k;m','o')

sum(grepl('^.{2}[abm]', x))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Nice. No need for the trailing `.*`. Maybe want a leading `^`

Comment: I think OP needs the 3rd character and not the 2nd. So should {2} be {4} in this case?

Comment: Nice answer.  Very compact.